# Hangfire - How to avoid multiple queueing for a job?

Tags: c#, redis, startup, hangfire

In Startup.cs, I want to enqueue a recurring job. Since there are multiple instances of IIS and these are connected to each other with Redis backplane, I don't want to queue it multiple times.

My aim is something like: **"if a job with this id is not queued before, enqueue it; otherwise, skip enqueueing since there is already a job running with given id"**.

How can I give custom id to a job? How can I do above execution?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What type of storage are you using to run HangFire? SQL? MongoDB? Redis?